# sqlalchemy postgres add comment on table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

While doing Declaring Mapping

```py
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()

class YourTableName(Base):    
    __tablename__ = 'YourTableName'

    pk  = sqlalchemy.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    val = sqlalchemy.Column(sa.Integer, comment="yeah row comment works")
```

how to add comment on table which can be easily done with psql console.

```sql
COMMENT ON TABLE public."YourTableName" is 'This is Table!';
```

Comment: thanks i found my answer! @Kendas